# crash when using android spinner adapter

Tags: android

crash when using two android spinner adapter, one adapter was using an integer-array as resource and the other was using a string-array as resource

```
2019-01-06 18:53:45.703 20508-20508/com.junkradar.junkradar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.junkradar.junkradar, PID: 20508
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:445)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:407)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:204)
        at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:602)
```

Answer (score 0):

the cause - 
I was used an integer-array as the resource for one of the adapters, and it appears the adapter works with string-arrays only.

After changing to String array the issue was resolved